# Why YouTube videos playing in landscape mode not in (vertically )portrait mode?

Tags: android, youtube

Any help is appreciated.
I also want  to make the videos downloadable as these are public video.

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {

String url = " ";
private int REQ_PLAYER_CODE = 1;
private static String YT_KEY = "some keys";
```

I am getting the URL from another class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    // Intent in=getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String url = bundle.getString("key");
    Log.v("in mainactivity", "" + url);


    assert url != null;
    Intent videoIntent = null;
    if (url != null) {
        videoIntent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(this, YT_KEY, url, 0, true, false);
    }

    startActivityForResult(videoIntent, REQ_PLAYER_CODE);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQ_PLAYER_CODE && resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.getReturnedInitializationResult(data);
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, 0).show();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format("PLAYER ERROR!!", errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

 }
```

Is there anything I can do to play videos in any mode depending on the user.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `lightboxMode` to `true` to play in portrait mode.

`videoIntent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(this, YT_KEY, url,0, true,true);`